# Is the transfer process of files from HDFS to ADLS Gen 2 using command line same as the transfers to BLOB?

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

In my project, we have been using BLOBs on Azure. We were able to upload ORC files into an existing BLOB container named, say, `student_dept` in quite a handy manner using:

`hdfs fs -copyFromLocal myfolder/student_remarks/*.orc wasbs://student_dept@universitygroup.blob.core.windows.net/DEPT/STUDENT_REMARKS`

And we have a Hive EXTERNAL table: `STUDENT_REMARKS` created on the `student_dept` BLOB. This way, we can very easily access our data from cloud using Hive queries.

Now, we're trying to shift from BLOB storage to ADLS Gen2 for storing the ORC files and I'm tring to understand the impact this change would have on our upload/data retrieval process.

I'm totally new to Azure, and what I want to know now is how do I upload the ORC files from my HDFS to ADLS Gen2 stoage? How different is it?

Does the same command with the different destination (ADLS G2 instead of BLOB) work or is there something extra that needs to be done in order to upload data to ADLS G2?

Can someone please help me with your inputs on this?

Comment: Can you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't give it a try, but as per doc like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-use-hdfs-data-lake-storage#delete-a-file-or-directory) and [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyFromLocal), you can use command like below for ADLS GEN2:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal myfolder/student_remarks/*.orc 
       abfs://student_dept@universitygroup.dfs.core.windows.net/DEPT/STUDENT_REMARKS
```